# How to use my own version of a standard package

Tags: debian, apt

I encountered a problem with Nautilus for which I did not find any solution other than downloading the source code, making some changes and compiling it on my own. So now I have two versions of nautilus, the official version from the repositories and mine with a few changes. I would like to keep both.

What would be a good way to tell applications to use my own compiled version of Nautilus when starting Nautilus from within the application? (e.g. opening the Downloads folder with firefox)

I figured out that firefox calls `/usr/bin/nautilus` so I could just replace this with a symlink to my own program. However, I believe this symlink will be overwritten as soon as I install an update for Nautilus. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Putting your version in `/usr/local/bin` didn't work?  i.e. did firefox search your `$PATH` and find the version in `/usr/bin`, or does it (or your xdg-open stuff) hard-code `/usr/bin/nautilus`?  Installing your own version of something in /usr/local normally works.

Comment: I tried this just now and it did not work. I don't know what firefox does internally, but `/usr/bin/nautilus` seems to be hard-coded somehow. If it is removed firefox doesn't do anything anymore when I try to open the Downloads folder, although there is a symlink to my own version of nautilus in `/usr/local/bin`. My `$PATH` variable is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: If you're curious, you could run `strace -f -efile,execve -o firefox_syscalls.txt  firefox` to see what ff does.  If you search the log for `nautilus`, that might show you something.  (That `-e` filters the system calls for `execve` and file open/close / pathname stuff, otherwise it would be a flood of `futex` and socket read/write for X11).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would fix the packaged version of Nautilus, which might seem daunting at first but is easy enough — although it doesn’t survive package upgrades so it does require some discipline. (See [Wouter’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418854/86440) for details.)

The simplest approach in your situation is to add a diversion:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/nautilus.original --rename /usr/bin/nautilus
```

This will instruct `dpkg` to rename `/usr/bin/nautilus` to `/usr/bin/nautilus.original` whenever a package tries to install it. Then you can add your own symlink, and it will remain untouched even when the Nautilus package is upgraded. To remove it, run

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove /usr/bin/nautilus
```

You can apply the same technique for any other file you need to replace in a similar fashion, apart from some configuration files which aren’t handled correctly when diverted.

Answer (score 7):

The best long-term solution is to contact the nautilus developers and work with them on a patch to the official nautilus code, so that once the updated version of nautilus hits your system, you won't need to deal with this anymore.

Assuming you've done that, until that change trickles down to your system, you'll still need to deal with the issue of wanting to use your own patched version of nautilus.

The easiest way is to produce a package of nautilus with your patch already applied, and to install it in such a way that it won't be upgraded automatically.

On Debian (which according to the tags on this question you're using), the easiest way to accomplish that is:

```
apt-get install devscripts
apt-get build-dep nautilus # note, this also pulls in build-essential
apt-get source nautilus
cd nautilus-*
# apply your patch
dch -i
# Set the version number of the new changelog entry to something like x.y.z-a.local,
# where "x.y.z-a" is the version of the package as it existed prior to your patch,
# add a description of the change after the '*', then save and exit the editor
debuild -uc -us -i && sudo debi --upgrade
echo "nautilus hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

This builds a new package with your patch, installs it, and then marks it in dpkg so that it will not be auto-updated anymore.

The next time an updated version of the package will be released, apt will notify you that an updated version exists, but is being held back. You then need to do the above again.

Comment: `apt-mark hold packagename` is the modern way of holding a package.  (I even made my own `dpkg-hold`/`dpkg-unhold` scripts in `dlocate` use `apt-mark` instead of the `dpkg --set-selections` method they had used for years.  The scripts are obsolete because of apt-mark but I still have other scripts that call them, and removing them might break scripts written by other users of the dlocate package)

Comment: The section on hold in `man apt-mark` says `The command is only a wrapper around dpkg --set-selections and the state is therefore maintained by dpkg(1) and not affected by the --file option`, so I think that's a minor thing ;-)